# How to solve ObjectParameterError?

Tags: javascript, json, mongoose

Can you show me how to solve this error? Is there another way to send the array back into the console? The error says the params are incorrect, should I change the function to send it in another way? Thanks!

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const articleSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String
};

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

app.get("/articles", function(req, res) {
  Article.find("/articles", function(err, foundArticles) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(foundArticles);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Error code logged -

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got /articles
at model.Query.Query.find (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2098:16)
at Function.find (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2156:13)
at C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\app.js:27:11
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at SendStream.error (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
at SendStream.emit (events.js:375:28)
at SendStream.error (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\send\index.js:270:17)
at SendStream.onStatError (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\send\index.js:421:12)
at next (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\send\index.js:735:16)
at onstat (C:\Users\huang\Mandy's Useful Folders\Web Development\Wiki-API\node_modules\send\index.js:724:14)
```

Comment: Can you add the error that you're seeing to your post?

Comment: Please use this one thanks  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/commit/5c547ad49de1a70d679c526d5ba67d90605194ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [docs on querying](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-find) (and the error displayed) you need to pass in a query object to the `find(...)` method on your model.

So, try this instead:

```js
app.get("/articles", function(req, res) {
  Article.find({}, function(err, foundArticles) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(foundArticles);
    }
  });
});
```

Note that by passing in an empty object to `find` you're telling Mongo to return *everything* in the `Article` collection.